# why is making routes in this way does not work

Tags: node.js, routes

I was trying to make different methods for one route in a short and easy way that i saw in a video put i got this error
`Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String]`
i will put the part that made this problem below

```js
usersRouter.route('/whishlist')
    .post('/add', (req, res) => {
        try {
            let appartment_id = req.body.appartment_id;
            let customer_id = 405521014;
            let sql = 'insert into wishlist (customer_id,appartment_id)values(?,?)';
            connection.query(sql,[customer_id,appartment_id],(err,result)=>{
                if(err)
                throw err;
                res.send('added to wishlist successfully');
            })
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    })
    .get('/show', (req, res) => {
        try {
            let customer_id = 405521014;
            let sql = 'select * from wishlist'
            connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
            })

        } catch (error) {         
        }
    })
    .delete('/remove', (req, res) => {
        try {
            let appartment_id = req.body.appartment_id;
            let customer_id = 405521014;
            let sql = 'delete from wishlist where customer_id=? and appartment_id=?';
            connection.query(sql,[customer_id,appartment_id],(err,result)=>{
                if(err)
                throw err;
                res.send('remover from wishlist successfully');
            })
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    });

module.exports = usersRouter;
```

Comment: Which routing library are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

*I assume you're using [Express](https://expressjs.com/)*

It seems similar to the example under `app.route()` [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). According to the [router documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route), you can't "sub route" that route that way.